# Why can't inversion be used on a universally qualified hypothesis in Coq?

Tags: coq

I've been going through the Software Foundations course and found the following proof ([source link](https://github.com/moritanon/Coq_study/blob/master/MoreLogic.v#L63)).

```
Theorem not_exists_dist :
  excluded_middle ->
  forall (X:Type) (P : X -> Prop),
    ~ (exists x, ~ P x) -> (forall x, P x).
Proof.
  unfold not. intros.
  unfold excluded_middle in H.
  assert ((P x) \/ ((P x) -> False)) as HP.
  apply H with (P:=(P x)).
  inversion HP.
  apply H1.
  apply ex_falso_quodlibet. apply H0. exists x. apply H1.
Qed.
```

I'm curious, why is there an assertion saying `(P x) \/ ((P x) -> False)`, when if I `unfold excluded_middle in H` and `unfold not in H`, I'll get the exact same `H : forall P : Prop, P \/ (P -> False)` as the assertion, only that there's a universal quantifier.

This is even more obvious as the assertion can be proved just by doing `apply H`, and the whole reason for this step is to do `inversion HP` on the newly asserted hypothsesis.

The question is, why isn't it possible to do `inversion H` at the beginning directly, and spare the extra step of defining an assertion, which just copies one of the assumptions? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inversion` only works on things of inductive type, such as `or`. `forall` is not an inductive type constructor, hence one cannot perform `inversion` on it. One could maybe extend `inversion` to behave like `(e)destruct`: if you give it something that is universally quantified, it'll generate additional existentials and proof obligations that you need to fulfill to fill in the missing spots, as well as destructing the conclusion. However, this is not how it works right now...

One could do a more direct proof by just applying `H` and destructing it directly:

```
Theorem not_exists_dist :
  excluded_middle ->
  forall (X:Type) (P : X -> Prop),
    ~ (exists x, ~ P x) -> (forall x, P x).
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct (H (P x)).
  apply H1.
  exfalso. apply H0. exists x. apply H1.
Qed.
```